# Python 3: Error: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn for basic machine learning

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


X = df[['floors', 'waterfront','lat' ,'bedrooms' ,'sqft_basement' ,'view' ,'bathrooms','sqft_living15','sqft_above','grade','sqft_living']]
Y = df['price']
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X,Y)
```

However, whenever I try to train the model with more than one data type, I get

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

Anyone know why?

Data: https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DA0101EN/coursera/project/kc_house_data_NaN.csv

Edit: When checking for infinite values manually, I found none, however when checking using python every value type had infinites in them

Comment: Do any of your features contain `NaN`, `None` or np.inf` values, or data that is not numeric?

Comment: @Varun Suvvari Where do you import pandas and how you initialized the df dataframe?

Comment: @Varun can you provide sample of data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand how Machine Learning works, you should have values associated with the properties floors,waterfront etc and the **Y** should be float as well(ground truth) for each property. It's like when you want to predict the house prices based on a number of features (**X values**) like no of bedrooms, square meter of the house, how big is the kitchen and so on.

All these features should have values that describe them and the **Y values** should be the house selling price. So the processing of all these features and giving the actual selling price will train your model to make predictions on new data that it hasn't seen before.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#I have given sample float values to help you understand how you should implement it
x_data = {'Properties':['floors', 'waterfront','lat' ,'bedrooms' ,'sqft_basement' ,'view' ,'bathrooms','sqft_living15','sqft_above','grade','sqft_living'],
          'values':[1.2,2.2,0.4,5.3,0.2,2.3,1.2,4,1.3,3.2,0.8]}
y_data = {'Price':[100, 200, 500, 400, 220, 140, 150, 190, 300, 240, 59]}

#this is how you initialize pandas dataframe
X_df = pd.DataFrame(x_data)
Y_df = pd.DataFrame(y_data)

#I will need only the values from X dataframe and convert it to numpy array
X = X_df['values'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
Y = Y_df.to_numpy()

lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X,Y)
```

It will be better if you start from the basics and then move to more advanced topics.